# Script modification with library thread or multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to ask if someone could help me modify my script to use thread library or multiprocessing to get better performance. I'm a Python beginner and don't know all the basic libraries yet. And I don't know how to modify the "loop" variable to support any of these libraries.
I also have a problem with the "add" method, because when the "loop" method uses the "add" method, it does not add the record to the database immediately, only after the loop is finished in the "loop" method. Sorry for linguistic errors, I am using "Google Translate".

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import permutations
import requests
import mysql.connector
import time

class bot():

def __init__(self):
    self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="python"
    )
    self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()

def __del__(self):
    self.mydb.commit()

def add(self, url):
    try:
        self.odpowiedz = requests.get(url)
        if self.odpowiedz.status_code == 200:

            self.mycursor.execute('SELECT url FROM adresy WHERE url="' + str(url) + '"')
            self.results = self.mycursor.fetchall()
            self.checkUrl = self.mycursor.rowcount


            if int(self.checkUrl) == 0:
                self.html = self.odpowiedz.text
                self.html2 = BeautifulSoup(self.html, 'html.parser')
                # Informacje
                self.title = str(self.html2.title.string)
                self.sites = int(len(self.html2.find_all('a', href=True)))
                if self.html2.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'}):
                    self.description = str(self.html2.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'}).get('content'))
                elif self.html2.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'og:description'}):
                    self.description = str(self.html2.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'og:description'}).get('content'))
                else:
                    self.description = ''
                print(self.description)
                self.time = int(time.time())


                self.sql = "INSERT INTO adresy (title, url, sites, description, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                self.val = (self.title.strip(), url, self.sites, self.description, self.time)
                self.mycursor.execute(self.sql, self.val)
                print('dodano')
            else:
                print('ten adres juz istnieje')
    except:
        print('Podana strona nie istnieje')

def loop(self):
    self.znaki = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    self.perm = permutations(self.znaki, 4)
    self.n = 0
    for i in list(self.perm):
        m = ''
        for x in range(len(i)):
            m = m + str(i[x])
        self.add('http://'+m+".pl")
        self.n += 1
        print(self.n)
        if self.n == 300:
            break

bot = bot()
bot.loop()
```

Comment: It may be not very simple to add concurrency to the script which writes to database. But in this exact case it may be easy enough: have a look at multiprocessing.dummy, there's a very convenient `ThreadPool`, it may be the most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to make html, html2 and so instance attributes, they are not used anywhere outside of `add`. And in `loop` you can a) use string instead of list (or maybe better `string.ascii_lowercase` not to type them by hands); b) use `''.join(i)` instead of concatenating them in a loop and c) use permutations object in for clause without `list()`, it is more efficient.